# Group rows by timestamp and conditionally sum different columns

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to select some traffic flow data and create sums for the different traffic directions, bucketed in 60 second buckets.  Simplified table is below (timestamp is unix epoch):

```
Timestamp      Source     Destination    Count
1              inside     outside          5
2              inside     outside          6
3              outside    inside           7
65             inside     inside           4
66             inside     outside          6
72             inside     outside          7
```

Current Query (which does the bucketing, but doesn't have anything about direction)

```
SELECT sum(count) AS total FROM table GROUP BY round(timestamp/60)
```

This gives me the total count for each 60 second "bucket" like

```
Count
 18
 10
 7
```

Now, where I'm lost  (I can do this in the client code, but I'd kinda like to do it with the SQL if possible). I'd like to have a sum called inbound for every row with inside as source and dest as outside, a sum called outbound for every row with outside in source and inside as dest, and a row called internal where both source and dest are inside.  Still grouped by the 60 second bucket.  i.e. what I want back is:

```
Inbound  Outbound  Internal
   7        11        0
   0         6        4
   0         7        0
```

My SQL foo is weak, and I really don't know where to start  (I suspect I need a subselect, but I'm not sure how to construct it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should actually be able to do a pivot:

```
SELECT SUM(count) AS total
    , SUM(CASE 
              WHEN Source = 'outside' 
                   AND Destination = 'inside' 
                   THEN count  -- Use 1 if you only want to count each row
              ELSE 0 END) AS [Inbound]
    , SUM(CASE
              WHEN Source = 'inside' 
                  AND Destination = 'outside' 
                  THEN count
              ELSE 0 END) AS [Outbound]
    , SUM(CASE 
              WHEN Source = 'inside'
                  AND Destination = 'inside' 
                  THEN count
              ELSE 0 END) AS [Internal]
FROM table 
GROUP BY round(timestamp/60)
```

Comment: `THEN 1` should be `THEN count`?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  round(timestamp/60)             AS bucket,
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN source = 'inside'  AND destination = 'outside'
         THEN count ELSE 0
    END
  )                               AS outbound,
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN source = 'outside' AND destination = 'inside'
         THEN count ELSE 0
    END
  )                               AS inbound,
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN source = 'inside'  AND destination = 'inside'
         THEN count ELSE 0
    END
  )                               AS internal
FROM
  yourTable
GROUP BY
  round(timestamp/60)
```

Comment: Can the when clause be arbitrarily complicated?  i.e. when source between 1 and 10 AND dest between 11 and 20?

Comment: @skarface - yes, it can be - it just needs to be an expression that evaluates to a boolean.  See http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case

Comment: @skarface - Yes.  This is a standard pattern for `SUMIF()`.  It can be as complex as you wish, you can even make it treat different values with different weights... `SUM(CASE WHEN a=b THEN count WHEN a<b THEN -count WHEN a>b THEN count/2 ELSE 0 END)`